# flask session not reloading

Tags: python, session, flask

Right now I am using Flask and a flask 3rd party library [Flask-Session](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/)

Using the code below, I reload the page 4 times and get the following output:

```
set userid[0]
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2014 22:28:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
set userid[1]
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2014 22:28:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
set userid[2]
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2014 22:28:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
set userid[3]
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2014 22:28:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Code:

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask.ext.session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
sess = Session()

nextId = 0

def verifySessionId():
    global nextId

    if not 'userId' in session:
        session['userId'] = nextId
        nextId += 1
        sessionId = session['userId']
        print ("set userid[" + str(session['userId']) + "]")
    else:
        print ("using already set userid[" + str(session['userId']) + "]")
    sessionId = session.get('userId', None)
    return sessionId

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    userId = verifySessionId()
    return str(userId)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super secret key'
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'

    sess.init_app(app)

    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Shouldn't session['userId] be 'saved out' each time I reload the page?

Comment: Are cookies enabled? A session id is saved in a cookie, tied to the filesystem storage.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah... that was the issue. It's been a long few days with this, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have cookies enabled for sessions to work. Even Flask-Session cannot track a browser without those.

Flask-Session sets a cookie with a unique id, then later on finds your session data again by that cookie.